# ALTER TABLE causing transaction aborted

Tags: mysql, locking, deadlock, google-cloud-sql

There are two transactions. One transaction I used `BEGIN RO` for read-only transaction. While the other one I used `BEGIN` to allow me adding a new column to my table called `dummy_table`. This is what I've done :

[image: The transcation is aborted]

However, after committing (even though I'm getting error transaction aborted), the column is successfully added.

For testing, I tried to `UPDATE` one of the row instead, the tx2 able to `COMMIT` successfully.
May I know what is the cause of the problem? Why is adding column causing the transaction to abort? What kind of improvement can I do?

Comment: I'll remove the PostgreSQL tag, ok?

Comment: Is this really mysql? As far as I know there's no `CLOSE;` statement and I can't find anything in the documentation about it. `CLOSE;` results in a syntax error.

Comment: I used Google Spanner so Im not very sure which SQL language they use. but its the most similar to MySQL so far.

Comment: What datatype is ip_addrs supposed to be?  Etc.  The `ALTER` is incomplete.